# showing one record within 48 hours using sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having an issue with my date values and the data types for the date field is date-time but at the sametime i am getting a lot of records for the same id within 48 hours. The goal is just to return one record only if patient makes visit to the hospital within 48.  For example if patient A goes to ER on 1/1/2014 and again goes back to 1/2/2014 then i only want to show the first visit which 1/1/2014.  I really believe the issue is at this line

```
AND A.[ADMT_TS] < DateAdd(d, 2, ADMT_TS)
```

and i think i need to do some conversion first in order to get the correct values.
here is my query and please not that i have other queries before the select statement here but i am only posting this section which where i am trying to get the first 48 hours.

```
SELECT [ID], [LOCATION], [ADMT_TS] 
FROM ERS WHERE RN = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT [ID], [LOCATION], [ADMT_TS] 
FROM ERS A 
WHERE RN > 1 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ERS WHERE RN = 1 AND [ID] = A.[ID])
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ERS WHERE RN = 1 AND [ID] = A.[ID] AND A.[ADMT_TS] < DateAdd(d, 2, ADMT_TS))
```

Comment: What if a patient visit ER 3 times on Jan 1, Jan 2, and Jan 4? What do you expect to see?

Comment: it would greatly help if you used sqlfiddle.com and posted some data.   You are really looking for the first occurrence of every patient that uses the ER, Correct?

Comment: Are you storing only the date values in `ADMT_TS`, or does it contain both date and time values? The extra hours might be messing you up. Also, how is `RN` set/assigned? Are there extra "1" rows in there? The query gives no indication of how the underlying data "fits together".

Comment: please see my first post, i have updated my entire query

Answer (score 0):

This will work but may not be the best option. If you post some data and give us an idea of how many rows may/will be in ERS table, I can adjust the query if needed

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Loc]
      ,MIN([admt_ts])
FROM [NewJunk].[dbo].[ERS]
WHERE RN = 1
GROUP BY id, loc
```